# How to use decltype in this case

Tags: c++, using, decltype

Here is my code:

```
class Test
{
private:
    SomeType a;
public:
    using TE = decltype(a.find("abc")->second);
    TE getElement(const string &) const;
};

Test::TE Test::getElement(const string & key) const
{
    return a.find(key)->second;
}
```

In the class, a function can return an element of `a` like above. The type of `a.find(key)->second` is very complicated so I don't want to type it all. In fact, I even don't know how to type it...

So I want to use `decltype` like above but failed. Here is the error:

> error C2227: left of '->second' must point to class/struct/union/generic type

Comment: _How_ did it fail?  Edit the exact error message into the question.

Comment: Works for me after fixing obvious problems: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b2b40702ad2c93cb

Comment: what is the return type of `a.find("abc")`?

Comment: Does `a` have to be declared in the class definition before the `decltype` statement?  Seems that way from Petr's example but I couldn't say for sure.

Comment: Seems like you already got the type of `a.find(key)` wrong, because the compiler thinks that `->second` cannot be applied to it. Maybe it is `a.find(key).second`?

Comment: `return a.find(key)-second;` I doubt this is what your code looks like. You meant to write `->second`

Comment: I suppose I should ask an obvious question: Are you compiling with C++11 or above?

Comment: Note, that `"abc"` is not `string`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to either move the definition of `a` up:

```
class Test
{
private:
    SomeType a;
public:
    using T = decltype(a.find("abc")->second);
    ...
};
```

Or, instead of `a`, substitute and expression of the correct type using [`std::declval`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval):

```
class Test
{
public:
    using T = decltype(std::declval<SomeType&>().find("abc")->second);
    ...
private:
    SomeType a;
};
```

---

Note that you're missing a `>` here:

```
    return a.find(key)-second;
                     ^^^
```

And that your `decltype()` expression is looking up a `const char[4]` instead of a `std::string const &`. So the most correct version would be:

```
using T = decltype(std::declval<SomeType&>().find(
                       std::declval<std::string const&>()
                       )->second);
```